# Powershell Script to Install Microsoft 2010

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy a file from the server to a pc to automatically install Microsoft Office 2010. I am getting the following error when just trying to use the CopyItem portion.

```
Start-Service : Service 'Remote Registry (remoteregistry)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot open remoteregistry service on computer 'IT-PCName'.
At line:21 char:54
+ Get-Service remoteregistry -ComputerName $computer | Start-Service
+                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

(Well I just figured out the above error is because the computer name and user name are different so that took care of that error, but the script is still not working because I am not sure how this line should read `$InstallString = '"C:\windows\temp\Office 2010\setup.exe" /adminfile Updates/OfficeSetup.MSP /config ProPlus.WW/config.xml"'`)

This is my code so far to copy Office 2010 to the pc to automatically run the install.

```
 ForEach ($computer in (GC (Get-FileName -InitialDirectory $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -Filter "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"))) {

    $filepath = Test-Path -Path "\\$computer\C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office"
         If ($filepath -eq $false)
         {
    Get-Service remoteregistry -ComputerName $computer | Start-Service
         Copy-Item -Path "\\server\Orig\Install\Office2010" -Destination "\\$computer\c$\windows\temp\" -Container -Recurse -Force
}
}
```

Once the file is transferred to the computer I was thinking the I could do something like this

```
ForEach ($computer in (GC (Get-FileName -InitialDirectory $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -Filter "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"))) {

$filepath = Test-Path -Path "\\$computer\C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office"
     If ($filepath -eq $false)
     {
Get-Service remoteregistry -ComputerName $computer | Start-Service
     Copy-Item -Path "\\server\Orig\Install\Office2010" -Destination "\\$computer\c$\windows\temp\" -Container -Recurse -Force
     $InstallString = '"C:\windows\temp\Office 2010\setup.exe" /adminfile Updates/OfficeSetup.MSP /config ProPlus.WW/config.xml"'
     ([WMICLASS]"\\$computer\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").Create($InstallString)

     "$computer" + "-" + "(Get-Date)" | Out-File -FilePath "\\server\Orig\Install\RemoteInstallfile.txt" -Append
     }
     Else
     {
     "$computer" + "_Already_Had_Software_" + "(Get-Date)" | Out-File -FilePath "\\server\Orig\Install\RemoteInstallfile.txt" -Append
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just had an extra " after config.xml

```
$InstallString = '"C:\windows\temp\Office 2010\setup.exe" /adminfile Updates/OfficeSetup.MSP /config ProPlus.WW/config.xml'
```